# Identical simultaneous queries and caching

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Say we have two servers making identical queries to the same database roughly once an hour, and the database gets updated rarely (every 30 minutes).  Getting the result back fast is not important, but we would like the data warehouse running for as short a time as possible.

Should we make sure that one of the queries completes before the other begins, so that the result is cached?  Is snowflake smart enough to realize when it is being asked to run two identical queries, and only does the work once?

Comment: I don't think so.  Snowflake will check on cached results as part of the compiling process, which doesn't check on "other compiling queries".  So, both queries would not see a cached result and therefore receive an execution plan and execute separately.

Answer (score 0):

As referenced from the documentation snowflake queries results are persisted for 24 hours. So if nothing has changed to the query snowflake does not regenerate results. This we have tested in all our applications.

Below is the link please check and let me know if this helps.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-persisted-results.html

Comment: This says a cached result is used if "the persisted result for the previous query is still available", but if the identical queries are started simultaneously then I worry that a persisted result is not yet available.

Comment: can you debug this ? Can you put a timer to your query and find out the timings ? That way you will be sure. Also what I have seen is if I query for a month initial query takes time. But after that if I use a date range from that month I chose before then its pretty fast.So I would say yes but you can check also from snowflake history UI page as well.